# How to include the reference of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll from another folder rather than bin folder

Tags: c#, .net

I am using C#.net MVC application.Used DocumentFormat.OpenXml for a Export To Excel Feature. I am using Subversion (Tortoise SVN).It works fine.But When I commit to SVN on the Other End another developer getting a Error on assembly.

Error:Could not open the selected folder.
Could not load a file or assembly 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll,version=2.0.5022.0, culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.

What should I do If I want to add reference from another Folder as example from LIB folder.

Please guide me to solve this issue...

Comment: I expect you would need to add it into the GAC.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure without looking to your code, but try check did you make Add with svn tool for your library for both .dll file and LIB folder. Is second developer have this library on his side?

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Anthony Horne's comment:

> 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll,version=2.0.5022.0, culture=neutral,
>   **PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'**

The PublicKeyToken indicates that this is a strong-named assembly. Did you install OpenXML on your computer or just unzip the binaries? (If I remember correctly it OpenXML is generally distributed as an installation.)

I am guessing that your project is not be referencing the binary you committed to SVN, but the one in your GAC (which would be missing on your colleague's computer).

You don't **need** to use the GAC, but then you need to make sure your project is referencing the dll's correctly.